# .NET EF 6 Pluralization with prefix in table names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, plural

Plural table names are default convention in EF. but when I have added the prefix I can not make names anymore plural unfortunately. Any ideas?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
  modelBuilder.Types()
              .Configure(entity => entity.ToTable("MyPrefix_" + entity.ClrType.Name));

  modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Avoid using Pluralization... Use [Table] attibute or HasName instead

Comment: Yeah. Never saw a reason for that. Just because EF has some not too smart defaults does not mean you have to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **PluralizingTableNameConvention** uses a **PluralizationService** that can be used anywhere. So you can go ahead and use it in your configuration code.

Here is an example using a Model "Person" which should be pluralized to "People":

```
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var serv = PluralizationService.CreateService(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"));

        modelBuilder.Types()
         .Configure(entity => entity.ToTable("MyPrefix_" + serv.Pluralize(entity.ClrType.Name)));

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

After running this code it will correctly pluralize the Persons model to "MyPrefix_People" in the database.

To you use the PluralizationService you will have to reference the `System.Data.Entity.Design` assembly.